# Is it possible to make slideshow with u3d files in a beamer template?

Tags: beamer, packages, 3d, animate, movie15

I'm just interested if there is a technical way to merge between `animate` package and `movie15` package in order to get an interactive 3D slideshow (like that shown below in the link) with full features of `movie15`, like including `.u3d` files, rotating and zooming each 3D figure in each slideshow.

http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf

The above link gives an example of how to make an interactive slideshow, but without 3D capability of each slide that can be satisfied by using `movie15` package

I have tried to find someone documents or information regarding this point, but I think either it is impossible or still nobody did that.

I think if it is possible, then it will be a great add-on that could help everyone.

Comment: It is possible to switch between several u3d models within the same 3D widget using JavaScript. However, the `media9` package should be given preference over `movie15`, nowadays.